# Creating a table with two colon delimited strings

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am currently trying to make a PL/SQL function that takes two colon delimited strings as arguments.  The objective is to create a table that uses one of the colon delimited strings and separate the strings so that each sub-string is the name of a column of type varchar2(100).  The other string contains the values of a column that is hard coded into the table.

It would be helpful for other features of the code if the two strings were separated into elements in a VARRAY.

Here's a visual representation of what I want to happen.

String 1 = 'Value1:Value2:Value3'

String 2 = 'ValueA:ValueB'

(The amount of values of these strings won't be the same each time the code is ran)

| Hard-Coded Column | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 |  |  |
| Value2 |  |  |
| Value3 |  |  |

Comment: It is not good design to represent lists in scalar types. Use real collections for this purpose.

Comment: Is it possible to make a collection with dynamic size?

Comment: You're describing the solution you have in mind and are asking for help on how to implement it. Can you take a step back and describe the business problem you're trying to solve ? From what you have posted it seems you have taken a route to a very complex solution . Most probably there are simpler ways to achieve what you want but for that you need to tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to create a "table view" inside apex where you select the columns you want from a checkbox list and the row data you want in one of those columns with a different checkbox list.  Since the amount of columns will be varying the only way I think I can do this is by creating a new table each time the code is executed and deleting it once the page is closed

Comment: That is a very complex route you're taking to solve that. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using a report type of "Function returning SQL Query". This is done on the sample emp table.

1. Create page item `P146_COLS` of type checkbox group with source sql query `select column_name d, column_name r FROM user_tab_columns where table_name = 'EMP'`
2. Create page item `P146_ROWS` of type checkbox group with source sql query `SELECT ename, empno FROM emp`
3. Create button to submit the page.
4. Create a region of type "static report" with settings like below.

[image]

5. Set source of report to

```
DECLARE
  l_query VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := NVL(:P146_COLS,'EMPNO');
  l_rows VARCHAR2(4000) := NVL(:P146_ROWS,1);
  l_cols_arr  apex_t_varchar2;
  l_rows_arr  apex_t_varchar2; 
  
BEGIN
  l_cols_arr := apex_string.split(p_str => l_cols, p_sep => ':');
  l_rows_arr := apex_string.split(p_str => l_rows, p_sep => ':');
  l_query := 'SELECT ';
  FOR i IN 1..l_cols_arr.count
  LOOP
    l_query := l_query||l_cols_arr(i)||', ';
  END LOOP;
  l_query := RTRIM(l_query,', ')||' FROM EMP';
  l_query := l_query ||' WHERE ';
  
  FOR i IN 1..l_rows_arr.count
  LOOP
    l_query := l_query|| 'empno = '||l_rows_arr(i)||' OR ';
  END LOOP;
  l_query := RTRIM(l_query,' OR ');
  apex_debug.info(p_message => l_query);
  RETURN l_query;
END;
```

5. Add a serverside condition to the report region of type "Expression" with source `:P146_COLS IS NOT NULL AND :P146_ROWS IS NOT NULL`
6. Run it:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful but I need to create a table each time instead of pulling from a pre-existing table, could I build a create table query similar to how you did and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, then reference it after it is created?

Comment: Do you really need a table or do you just need to see the query results ? Have you looked at storing the data in apex_collections instead ? Or using a view ? A table seems like a lot of overhead

Comment: I really just need to see a grid view of some columns that don't exist before hand and some rows that also don't exist before hand.  I'm relatively new to oracle apex so if this doesn't make sense I can try to explain it better, but if using a view or apex_collections accomplishes this easier than im all ears.

Comment: Trust me, you don't need a table. What you see on the screen is a results of a query. An end user doesn't care if that is from a table, a view, a rest data source or an ad hoc generated query.

Comment: But... you're new to apex and this is a pretty complicated thing you're trying to achieve. APEX offers a great deal of functionality out of the box. I suggest you look into interactive reports/interactive grids. They offer filter functionality in the UI (to select the rows) and allow the user to only display the column they want (and save that as a report). That functionality covers both your requirements (not all rows and not all columns)

Comment: I think you're overlooking the issue that the total number of columns needs to be dynamic I understand you can make server-side conditions for reports and grids but that would make adding new columns that much more work

Comment: In the solution I suggested the columns and rows are dynamic. What didn't work with that ?

Comment: The solution gets me a great deal of the way towards solving my problem but my one issue is that it is pulling columns from a table that already exists.  The columns I want shown in the table don't exist as columns anywhere in my schema but the data necessary to build the columns does exist as rows.  For this reason I don't believe a view would work either.

Comment: ok... I have no idea what that means... "the columns I want shown in the table don't exist as columns anywhere in my schema". I don't think it makes sense to continue this discussion in the comments. If you put together a question that explains exactly what you're trying to achieve I happy to give it try. 
Please do remember to *mark your questions as answered* if they actually answer your question.